# Show that $ f(x,y) = \left\{ \begin{array}{c} 1\mbox{ for } xy \neq 0, \\ 0 \mbox{ for } xy = 0 \end{array} \right. $ is not continuous at origin

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

$$ f(x,y) = 
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}1 \mbox{ for } xy \neq 0,
\\0 \mbox{ for } xy = 0
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

a) Show that $f(x,y)$ is not continuous at the origin

b) Show that the partial derivatives at the origin exist

c) Verify the existence of the partial derivatives for all points $(x,y)$ where $xy = 0$.

I solved b) this way

$$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(t,0)-f(0,0)}{t} = 0 \\
\lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(0,t)-f(0,0)}{t} = 0$$

As for the others I am lost. For a) since the function goes $1$ on both sides and then drops to zero then intuitively it isn't continuous but I don't know how to prove it. Is

$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}f(x,y) = 0$$

?

Comment: Limit has $\epsilon - \delta$ definition, right?  Use that for a).

Comment: @GEdgar How do I do that?

Comment: This is an exercise to make you think about that $\epsilon - \delta$ definition, to understand it.  So you should at least begin, not us.  To show $$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}f(x,y) $$ does not exist, what do you need to do?

Comment: @GEdgar I need to prove that $|f(x,y)-L| < \epsilon$?

Comment: first consider the case $x=x,y=0$. Check whether the partial derivatives exist at such $(x,y)$. Then reverse the case and find out what happens. And for the origin, you have your answer.

Comment: You may have mistyped (c)?  When $xy=$, either $x=0$ or $y=0$ and then only one partial derivative exists unless $x=y=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Use shall simply use sequential criteria for continuity on $\mathbb R^2$.
 Take the sequence $\{(0,\frac{1}{n})\}$ and $\{(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})\}$ both of the converges to $(0,0)$ in 
$\mathbb R^2$.

Now look at $\{f(0,\frac{1}{n})\}$ and $\{f(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})\}$.
The first one is constant sequence 0 and the second one is constant sequence 1. 
This shows that $f$ is not continuous at origin